# Sharpe Ratio of a Long-Short Portfolio

Tags: volatility, finance, sharpe-ratio, performance, longshort

I have a portfolio High and Low (according to the highest profit). From this I have formed my long short portfolio and calculated my Sharpe Ratio. How to interpret this correctly? Does a positive Sharpe Ratio in the long short portfolio mean that my portfolio High has performed better than my portfolio Low?
Thanks

Comment: Based on your explanation, I find it hard to understand what you did. Would you mind sharing some details? In my opinion, [SR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharpe_ratio) itself always has the same interpretation as explained in the link.

Answer (score 0):

If your Sharpe ratio is positive when you are long your high portfolio and short your low portfolio, your high portfolio had larger returns than the low portfolio.

Your mean return of the long-short portfolio is positive. This is only possible if, on average, the sum of the long return and the short return is positive.